# Moving files from node_modules to wwwroot in .NET Core

Tags: javascript, css, .net-core, node-modules

I am using a package.json to get Bootstrap, FontAwesome, jQuery and jQuery UI. Those packages go to the node_modules folder that is at the same level that wwwroot folder. I read about how to include that folder (node_modules) into the files that are served but how it is also not a good practice. My problem is that I can put the css and js files using bundleconfig.js into my wwwroot folder, but the fonts and images are not moved and cannot be used. How can I reference those files without putting the entire packages (that have tons of files that I won't use) into my wwwroot folder?

Comment: You could move the `node_modules` folder up one directory but I don't know if that would be preferable. I don't think there's a good solution.

Comment: I am reading now that Task Runners can be the solution but I still can't find how to move fonts and images that are needed only

Comment: I had a similar issue but with webpack. I copied the "assets" folder to the compiled folder. You can probably write a quick script for that in VS Build Events.

Comment: I solved it in another way, not sure if it is "the best way", but I used yarn, changed the output directory to wwwroot/lib and then with autoclean I delete the files that I don't want